# In pure Excel, best way to return Named Range Referred To Address (no VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I have a cell which is a named range MyRange.
Whats the best way to return the address this refers to into a cell without VBA?

Comment: *without VBA* means it's not a programming question, and makes it off-topic here. General software questions go to [su] instead.

Comment: @KenWhite It is somewhat hard to make a sharp distinction between programming in Excel and merely using Excel. Sophisticated spreadsheet formula questions (and anything e.g. using named ranges coupled with `indirect` is on the sophisticated side) seem more akin to straightforward programming questions rather than end-user questions. Note also that VBA programmers often need to craft spreadsheet formulas. For all you know, this is part of a larger project which does use VBA.

Comment: @John: I didn't say a thing about complex formulas or anything else. **Basic Excel use** is not a programming question, any more than a basic questions about using the Windows OS are on topic here. There has to be a point of separation or we'll end up with *how do I use the menus in Excel* type questions here.

Comment: @KenWhite In this particular case, it seems to fall within the scope of the `excel-formula` tag (which OP probably should have used). It is far from a "how do I use the menus" type question. I agree with you that many Excel questions do belong on Super Users rather than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation on teylyn's second:

`=CELL("address",MyRange)&":"&CELL("address",INDEX(MyRange,ROWS(MyRange),COLUMNS(MyRange)))`

Regards

Answer (score 5):

For a single cell range you can use

```
=CELL("address",MyRange)
```

For a multi-cell range you can use

```
=CELL("address",MyRange)&":"&CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",MyRange)),ROWS(MyRange)-1,COLUMNS(MyRange)-1))
```